# Animate widgets in Flutter but remove them from UI when hidding

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a simple page in which I display in the center a `TextFormField`. There is also a `FloatingActionButton` and when clicked, the `TextFormField` fade out and a new one fade in.

This works fine with packages like [animate_do](https://pub.dev/packages/animate_do) or [flutter_animate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate). But my problem comes when the first `TextFormField` fade out, because it's still taking the visible space in the UI. So when the second one pops up, it's not center (well, neither the 1st one).

So my scenario is:

- 1st input fade in
- Click Next
- 1st input fade out
- 2nd input fade int
  All inputs are center

This is the code. It shows an error having the setState (also explained [here](https://github.com/Klerith/animate_do_package/issues/29)):

```
import 'package:animate_do/animate_do.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewStoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewStoryPage({super.key});
  @override
  NewStoryPageState createState() => NewStoryPageState();
}

class NewStoryPageState extends State<NewStoryPage> {
  final _nameFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _ageFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _ageController = TextEditingController();
  late AnimationController nameAnimationController;
  late AnimationController ageAnimationController;
  int animationDuration = 2;
  int formStep = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('New Story'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: forms(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: formStep > 0,
            child: backButton(),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 16),
          nextButton(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget forms() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Form(
          key: _nameFormKey,
          child: nameTextField(),
        ),
        Form(
          key: _ageFormKey,
          child: ageTextField(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget nameTextField() {
    return FadeIn(
      controller: (controller) => nameAnimationController = controller,
      duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _nameController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "What's the protagonist name?",
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget ageTextField() {
    return FadeIn(
      controller: (controller) => ageAnimationController = controller,
      manualTrigger: true,
      duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _ageController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "And how old is he/she?",
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget backButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
      heroTag: null,
      onPressed: back,
      label: Text('Back'),
    );
  }

  Widget nextButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
      heroTag: null,
      onPressed: next,
      label: Text('Next'),
    );
  }

  Future<void> back() async {}

  Future<void> next() async {
    if (!_nameFormKey.currentState!.validate()) return;

    if (formStep == 0) {
      await nameAnimationController.reverse();
      await ageAnimationController.forward();

      setState(() {
        formStep = 1;
      });
      return;
    }

    if (!_ageFormKey.currentState!.validate()) return;

    if (formStep == 1) {
      await ageAnimationController.reverse();
      // TODO
    }
  }
}
```